# How to ignore login and logout requests in JMeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm trying to test the performance of our webapp with JMeter. The login procedure includes some external dependencies that can't be reproduced during the test, so I've programmed an alternate login. As this alternate login request is not part of the normal workflow I would like to exclude the login request from the JMeter results because the response time is pretty high compared to the other normal requests.

Is there a way to collect results only for a set of requests, ignoring the rest?

Comment: FYI I've filed https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54846, you can vote for it. I think a patch shouldn't be hard but I'm not sure I care enough. The hardest part would be for the project leads to agree with this feature.

Comment: @akostadinov, So what's the status after 2 years?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TO my knowledge, there is not an easy way to exclude.  However, by changing your structure, you can get what you want.

The Listeners tune into all children levels. Thus, if you have the listener as a direct child to the "test plan", all thread groups will be grabbed by the listener.  If you have multiple threadgroups, and place the listener in Threadgroup A, it will not capture results from Threadgroup B. The same applies for Simple Controllers also.

I would suggest the following structure:

```
Test Plan
- Thread Group
---- Simple Controller - Login ONLY
---- Simple Controller - Rest of Script
--------- Listener
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this old question!

Comment: Thanks @BlackGaff this works nicely. I've moved my login configs under the Thread Group and added a controller for the other stuff I wanted to report on.

Answer (score 12):

Since JMeter 4.0 it is possible to add **SampleResult.setIgnore()**  to tell JMeter to ignore SampleResult by Listeners.

> Reference: https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--

P.S. `SampleResult` variable in case of Beanshell, `sampleResult` for JS and `prev` for Groovy, see jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html.

Comment: To ignore the listener from the report, add a `JSR223 PostProcessor` inside the listener by selecting groovy as script language. use the following script `prev.setIgnore()`.

Comment: How can I conditionally ignore the sampler result only if it contains a certain error such as "java.net.SocketException: Socket closed"?