# Avoid or prevent jmeter listeners to stop logging samplers

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a listeners issue which are adding samplers information logging which I dont want the listeners to record as it corrupts the results 'xml' file. Below is the execution sequence of my script:

Is there any option in jmeter that restricts the listeners to add up log information of some listeneres.

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412649/how-to-ignore-login-and-logout-requests-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean):

> Use CLI mode: `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl`
>
> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the `-l` flag as above **they can all be deleted or disabled.**

So I would recommend [**removing your listeners completely**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) as they don't add any value just consume resources causing unnecessary CPU cycles and disk IO consumption and use only [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) for storing your test results. If default format doesn't work for you for any reason you can choose what to store by manipulating properties responsible for the [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)